# How can I set toolchain path in Conan with CMake for different users?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, conan, toolchain

I have multiple repos which use multiple toolchains. Each developer installed the toolchains in different path. I have multiple profiles to handle each of the supported toolchains, for example the following profile:

```
target_host=aarch64-oe-linux

[env]
AR=$COMPILER_PATH/$target_host-ar
AS=$COMPILER_PATH/$target_host-as
CC=$COMPILER_PATH/$target_host-$cc_compiler
CXX=$COMPILER_PATH/$target_host-$cxx_compiler
PATH=["$COMPILER_PATH"]

[settings]
arch=armv8
compiler.version=9.3
```

Now, each developer/user installed the toolchain in a different path.
Setting `COMPILER_PATH` in this profile file means that each developer will need to modify this file, which is something I don't want.

I thought about defining this variable in a different file and include the second file in this file, e.g.:

```
include(toolchain-path.txt)
```

I can't commit this file to git, which means:

1. conan install command will fail with an error that this file does not exist. and it will be unclear what should be in it.
2. For CI I want to have default values that the developer will be able to change on their environment.
   What do you suggest, how can I have a default path for the toolchain and to be able to modify it for different environments?

Comment: Some suggestions: Conan supports ``jinja`` templates, instead of using variables substitution, that is removed in Conan 2.0, using ``jinja`` templates is more recommended. You can use things like env-vars via ``os.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR")`` in your profile, to adapt to different machines that define such env-var. Also ``[env]`` way of defining the environment is legacy, and ``[buildenv]`` way is recommended to be 2.0-ready.

Comment: thank you. I will try to use `PROFILE_DIR` environment variable or to override the `generate` function in `conanfile.py`

Comment: quick update: `PROFILE_DIR` did not help

Comment: What about ``os.getenv()`` in Jinja profile syntax? You can try to submit a ticket to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues for further discussion.

Comment: I'm currently try to use os.getenv() with jinja as follows: ```{% set vars_filename = os.getenv("TOOLCHAIN_VARS_FILENAME", "default-toolchain-vars.txt") %}
{% include(vars_filename) %}``` but I found that the file that is defined with TOOLCHAIN_VARS_FILENAME must reside in the profile directory.

Comment: It is not clear, you cannot include a toolchain file, yo can include other profile. Maybe the "toolchain" filename is not the best? Maybe better file an issue in the repo.